# Package grffile not working consistently across machines

Tags: pdfpages

I have some latex code that uses includepdf and the grffile package.  I use the grffile package to allow spaces in the file path of a PDF I reference.

The code works on a desktop I have (i.e. the grffile package allows a PDF with a space in the file path), but the same code does not work on a laptop.

```
% This allows spaces to be used in file names or paths 
\RequirePackage[space]{grffile}  

\includepdf[pages=2-, width = \textwidth, keepaspectratio, pagecommand ={\thispagestyle{followingpage}}]{filePath}
```

The issue seems to be that the laptop is not executing the grffile package correctly.  I'm at a loss how to troubleshoot this.

One other piece of info, if I run the code on the laptop with the file path enclosed in speech marks, it works.

I am using the TeXworks editor / RStudio.

This is the log file from the desktop, where output is error free:
http://www.filedropper.com/xpreport-works

The first few lines of the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.7.24)  1 SEP 2015 11:16
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./XPReport.tex
(./XPReport.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(./XPTemplate.cls
Document Class: XPTemplate 
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
```

Then at line 589:

```
<use C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/
sig-on.pdf, page1 used on input line 19.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 578.16002pt x 578.19661pt.






<C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf, id=11, 614.2
95pt x 614.295pt>
File: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf Graphic 
file (type pdf)

<use C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/
sig-on.pdf used on input line 19.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 462.52977pt x 462.53854pt.





File: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf Graphic 
file (type pdf)

<use C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/
sig-on.pdf used on input line 19.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 462.52977pt x 462.53854pt.
```

This is the log file from the laptop, where output has file path error:
http://www.filedropper.com/xpreport-error

The first few lines of the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.8.21)  1 SEP 2015 11:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./XPReport.tex
(./XPReport.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(./XPTemplate.cls
Document Class: XPTemplate 
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
```

Then at line 589:

```
<use C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/
sig-on.pdf, page1 used on input line 19.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 578.16002pt x 578.19661pt.


LaTeX Warning: File `C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-
on.pdf' not found on input line 19.


<C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf, id=11, 614.2
95pt x 614.295pt>
File: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf Graphic 
file (type pdf)

<use C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/
sig-on.pdf used on input line 19.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 462.52977pt x 462.53854pt.


LaTeX Warning: File `C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-
on.pdf' not found on input line 19.

File: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf Graphic 
file (type pdf)

<use C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-on.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/
sig-on.pdf used on input line 19.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 462.52977pt x 462.53854pt.


LaTeX Warning: File `C:/Users/blahblah/Box Sync/R/dev/library/Correlation/sig-
on.pdf' not found on input line 19.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Inconsistency might be due to different file systems: remember that Windows is case insensitive, whereas Linux file systems are case sensitive.

Comment: That's one of the problems with spaces in file names: You must quote them and how to quote them can differ between pc. One can spent a lot of time to troubleshoot this. Why don't you avoid the spaces? Beside this: without more information about the OS, the versions of grffile and error messages it is difficult to say why it fails for you.

Comment: Sorry...should have stated...both machines are new (one month old), and both run Windows 7.

Comment: And which LaTeX installation?

Comment: @daleif - I added the log files above.

Comment: You are aware you can just paste them into your question? After pasting, highlight them and hit ctrl-k, then it will be formatted as source code. I'm currently on a tablet, so I cannot view those linked files.

Comment: @daleif - Yes, aware, but the files far exceed the character limit in a post.  I have added the top of the log files for each, and then the first section in which a significant discrepancy first appears.  The spaces in the file sample are to aid comparison (taken from a text compare tool).

Comment: There is actually a post limit?

Comment: Why are you specifying the full path to the files, what happens if the files are in the local folder and you just include the file busy name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27661/discussion-between-billelev-and-daleif).